# Odd box in chrome

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, responsive-design

I'm trying to place an animated `gif` over a `jpg`, and it seems to work in most browsers (IE, Firefox, iPhone, iPad), but there is a strange box around the animated `gif` in **chrome on windows**, **firefox for the mac**, and **chrome for the mac**.

I finally solved it through a few odd hacks, like forcing the image to resize to 99.9%, using a mask to only allow a portion of the animated gif to show through, but is there a better/cleaner cross browser solution?

I basically started with a div and an image inside, both of which are responsive.
HTML:

```
<div>
    <img src="http://www.enjoyillinois.com/images/animations/Garden_of_Gods_anim_full.gif" />
</div>
```

CSS:

```
div {
    background-image: url("http://www.enjoyillinois.com/images/animations/Garden_of_Gods_bg.jpg");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
}

img {
    width:100%;
    display:block;
}
```

Here is a jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/GyDCx/7/

Comment: pretty cool gif you have there. And plus 1 for a proper question construction

Comment: I noticed in Win7 Chrome it goes away when you resize the window. Not a solution, I know, but maybe a lead...

Comment: Yes, it goes away if you resize the window.  It will also go away if you tie an animation to it that triggers any kind of resize, that is until you scroll it off the screen and back on the screen, then it reappears again.

Comment: I also noticed the jpg and gif aren't quite lining up correctly, however, it lines up just fine on the live implementation, so I'm not worried about that.

Comment: Nice site! :: http://www.enjoyillinois.com

Comment: wow, great GIF and site there!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's a image edge scaling problem, the solution I use in such cases is:

```
img{ image-rendering:-webkit-optimize-contrast; }
```

That disables the blurry edge when scaling images.
http://jsfiddle.net/GyDCx/31/

Comment: This does appear to fix it for Chrome on my windows machine.  I'll have to retest it when I get back to the office on Tuesday for the Macs.  This is exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: This does indeed fix the issue on all the platforms I tested.  Nice answer!

Answer (score 2):

You can try:

```
-webkit-transform: translateZ( 0px );
```

This will fix it in Chrome.

see: http://jsfiddle.net/PvnmK/7/

**PS1:** also tested on safari and firefox.

Comment: Can't see the border even if I resize on chrome 27.0.1453.93 or even 17.0.963.66 for that matter

Comment: you mean the part where it misaligns? that's what the question is about.

Comment: From the @Jay Moretti Fiddle, if you make your `div` to be `inline-block;`, I assume that the problem is gone. But yes, when you stretch, the images doesnt scale uniformly - @user1846192

Comment: fixed by editing the original fiddle and just adding the transform: http://jsfiddle.net/PvnmK/7/